# How to improve proximity search in solr

Tags: search, solr

When I search for company in solr , the result should contain similar results such as com pany,comp-any and company.How to get that using solr.

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: Exactly what are the rules for what you consider a "similar result"?

Comment: If I search for Walmart, the result should display wal mart,wal-mart and walmart and viceversa.How to acheive this

Answer (score 0):

For the use case you provided, you can use n-grams.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="7"/>
</analyzer>
```

This filter breaks the tokens in parts of the specified sizes, like, for the word "company", will produce the following tokens: "com", "omp", "mpa", "pan", "any", "comp", "ompa", "mpan", "pany", "compa", "ompan", "mpany", "compan", "ompany", "company"

**TAKE CARE** This filter may degrade performance and makes your index grows exponentially, and possibly runs Solr out of memory depending on the size of the fields you're using it (i.e. if you use it for content extraction). So, choose wisely the field to use it :)

Here are some useful information with examples about it:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-N-GramFilter